# Trouble in inserting sub-documents using mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, subdocument

I created an Enterprise database using mongoose in node-express project.Now I need to add employee sub document in the enterprise_employee field of the enterprise database, but it throws an error.
Following code snippet is my schema

```js
var mongoose= require('mongoose');

var Enterprise= new mongoose.Schema({
     enterprise_id:{
  type:String
 },
 enterprise_name:{
  type:String
 },
 enterprise_email:{
  type:String
 },
 enterprise_employee: [{employee_id:Number, employee_name:String}]
});


module.exports={
 Enterprise:Enterprise
};
```

This code snippet is  the route for adding employee sub-document

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Enterprise = mongoose.model('Enterprise_gpy');

var addEmployee = function(req, res){

 Enterprise.findOne({"enterprise_id":req.body.enterprise_id},function(err, res){
  if(err){
   console.log('NO SUCH ORGANISATION');
   res.json(err);
  } else {
   Enterprise.enterprise_employee.push({
    "employee_id": req.body.employee_id,
    "employee_name":req.body.employee_name
   });
  }
 });
}
module.exports={
 addEmployee:addEmployee
};
```

This the error thrown

> throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^ TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like what you need is an update operation that uses the **`$push`** operator to add the elements to the array field. The following example demonstrates this:

```
Enterprise.findOneAndUpdate(
    { "enterprise_id": req.body.enterprise_id },
    {
        "$push": {
            "enterprise_employee": {
                "employee_id": req.body.employee_id,
                "employee_name":req.body.employee_name
            }
        }
    },
    { "new": true }, // return the modified document
    function(err, enterprise) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('NO SUCH ORGANISATION');
            res.json(err);
        } else {
            console.log(enterprise); // modified document
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because your schema needs to define the enterprise_employee as an array.  You have to explicitly tell Mongoose that it should be an 'Array' type.

Try this:

```
enterprise_employee: {
    type: Array,
    fields: [
        {
            employee_id: String,
            employee_name: String
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Error persists.Can you review me is this the right way of sending the details?{"enterprise_id" :2, "employee_id": 1 ,"employee_name" : "akila"}

Comment: In your case, the employee_id and enterprise_id are numbers not strings since there aren't quotes around them.  

Also you should try chridam's suggestion, it might be a cleaner way of doing what you're trying to do.